# Multi dimensional diagonal matrix where diagonal elements are row vectors or column vectors

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 3-dimensional matrix x with shape (2,4,6)

```
x = np.arange(2*4*3).reshape(2,4,3)
```

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23]]])
```

I want to create two diagonal matrices ei and ej with shape (2,4,4,1,3) and (2,4,4,3,1) such that diagonal elements of ei and ej are row vectors and column vectors of elements in x.

0-th element of ei : 
[ei[0]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb1n3.png)

0-th element of ej : 
[ej[0]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRSYR.png)

For example

```
ei = array([[
        [[[ 0.,  1.,  2.]],
         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]]],


        [[[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
         [[ 3.,  4.,  5.]],
         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]]],

        ...

        [[[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
         [[21., 22., 23.]]]]])
```

My naive way is given below

```
ei = np.zeros([x.shape[0],x.shape[1],x.shape[1],1,x.shape[2]])
ej = np.zeros([x.shape[0],x.shape[1],x.shape[1],x.shape[2],1])

for j in range(x.shape[0]):
  for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    ei[j,i,i] = x[j,i]
    ej[j,i,i] = np.transpose([x[j,i]])
```

Is there an alternative way of doing the same?

Answer (score 1):

We can define an n-dimensional zero matrix and fill it's diagonal using advanced indexing:

```
def to_nd_diagonal(x):
    *i, j, k = x.shape
    a = np.zeros((*i,j,j,k))
    I = np.arange(j)
    a[...,I,I,:] = x
    out=a[...,None]
    return out, out.swapaxes(-1,-2)
```

---

Where we get:

```
ej, ei = to_nd_diagonal(x)

ei.shape
# (2, 4, 4, 1, 3)
ej.shape
# (2, 4, 4, 3, 1)
```

---

```
print(ei)

array([[[[[ 0.,  1.,  2.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]]],


        [[[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 3.,  4.,  5.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]]],


        [[[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 6.,  7.,  8.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]]],


        [[[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 9., 10., 11.]]]],



       [[[[12., 13., 14.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]]],


        [[[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[15., 16., 17.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]]],


        [[[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[18., 19., 20.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]]],


        [[[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

         [[21., 22., 23.]]]]])

print(ej)

array([[[[[ 0.],
          [ 1.],
          [ 2.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]]],


        [[[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 3.],
          [ 4.],
          [ 5.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]]],


        [[[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 6.],
          [ 7.],
          [ 8.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]]],


        [[[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 9.],
          [10.],
          [11.]]]],



       [[[[12.],
          [13.],
          [14.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]]],


        [[[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[15.],
          [16.],
          [17.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]]],


        [[[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[18.],
          [19.],
          [20.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]]],


        [[[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[ 0.],
          [ 0.],
          [ 0.]],

         [[21.],
          [22.],
          [23.]]]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `range` loops with `np.arange` indexing:

```
In [260]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)                                                                           
In [261]: res = np.zeros((3,3,4),int)                                                                                
In [262]: res[np.arange(3), np.arange(3),:] = arr                                                                    
In [263]: res                                                                                                        
Out[263]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]])
```